# Is it possible to create a countdown using purely html?

Tags: html

Is it possible to create a countdown timer using purely HTML?

I mean no javascript or iframe or external CSS. just basic HTML and embedded style sttributes - i.e. `<h1 style="CSS GOES HERE">TEXT GOES HERE</h1>`.

Is this possible?

if so, how?

Comment: No, it isn't. HTML is static and you can't program anything with it.

Comment: @SLaks - `no javascript or iframe or external CSS. just basic HTML and embedded style tag`

Comment: @Oded: Exactly.  `<style>` tag.

Comment: @SLaks - I believe OP means `style` attributes.

Comment: @Oded CSS3 is embeddable in style tags is it not?

Comment: @Oded I believe he meant exactly what he said, "external" i.e. in a different file.

Comment: yes something like `<h1 style="CSS GOES HERE">TEXT GOES HERE</h1>`

Comment: @Jon - What is the difference between CSS that is external vs embedded? That is, would it be different CSS?

Comment: @SLaks so is it possible using `<style>`? if so, can you site an example how I can do it? thanks

Comment: "Just curious…" - usually a good indicator of a question that isn't a good fit for SO.

Comment: @Oded exactly the same, however sometimes people need to only serve a single file (i.e. a single html file)  This could be for emails etc.

Comment: @Abizern yes im curious... thats why Im asking a question :)

Comment: @Oded thanks for editing my question. thats exactly what I mean. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an animated gif.

The html would look like this.

```
<img src="countdown.gif" alt="countdown">
```

where `countdown.gif` is a reference to your countdown image.

Actually creating the image is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: can you show me how? thanks

Comment: @anagnam: I added an html fragment to show you how to use the `img` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to cobble something together using a `<meta http-equiv="refresh"` tag and some static pages.

Answer (score 1):

No. HTML is a mark-up language, not a script language. Mark-up languages are static, you can set them once. If you need interaction, you need a client-side script language like JavaScript.

> **Side Note**
>
> It is possible with only CSS3 animations: http://codepen.io/WouterJ/details/brguf
>   But be aware that CSS3 is not stable yet and the CSS3 animation API is far from stable. More information on [canIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.  HTML is completely static unless you use something such as javascript to make it dynamic.

As @SLaks suggested though it is possible using CSS3 animations but this will not be supported in older browsers.